# How to add a SAP UI5 application to Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5

I have a MTA project and I am trying to add the UI5 application to the Fiori Launchpad. But currently, the tiles do not show up. Instead when I check the console, I see that the target mapping has not been done properly. Can you please suggest where I do the target mapping.

This is the error I receive -

[image: Firori app]

The following is the manifest file of GroupManage app. There are other apps/tiles such as quickLoader, messageBuilder etc.

manifest.json -

```
{
    "_version": "1.7.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "com.sap.groups",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponent",
            "version": "0.0.0"
        },
        "dataSources": {
            "mainService": {
                "uri": "/odata/sah.svc/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "odataVersion": "2.0",
                    "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        },
        "supportedThemes": [
            "sap_hcb",
            "sap_belize"
        ]
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "com.sap.groups.view.groupList",
            "type": "XML"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.ui.layout": {},
                "sap.ushell": {},
                "sap.collaboration": {},
                "sap.ui.comp": {},
                "sap.uxap": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "com.sap.groups.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "": {
                "dataSource": "mainService",
                "settings": {
                    "metadataUrlParams": {
                        "sap-documentation": "heading"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "com.sap.groups.view",
                "controlId": "app",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "async": true
            },
            "routes": [{
                "pattern": "",
                "name": "groupList",
                "target": "groupList"
            }, {
                "pattern": "details/{groupId}",
                "name": "details",
                "target": "groupDetails"
            }],
            "targets": {
                "groupList": {
                    "viewName": "groupList",
                    "viewId": "groupList"
                },
                "groupDetails": {
                    "viewName": "groupDetails",
                    "viewId": "groupDetails"
                }
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "css/style.css"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And the site-content.json of the project is as follows -

```
{
    "_version": "1.0.0",
    "site": {
        "_version": "1.0",
        "identification": {
            "id": "....",
            "namespace": "",
            "entityType": "site",
            "description": "",
            "i18n": "",
            "title": "{{LAUNCHPAD_SAMPLE}}"
        },
        "payload": {
            "groupsOrder": [
                "user-applications",
                "configuration-applications"
            ],
            "config": {

            },
            "sap.cloud.portal": {
                "_version": "1.2.0",
                "config": {
                    "theme.id": "sap_belize",
                    "theme.active": "[\"sap_hcb\",\"sap_belize_plus\",\"sap_belize\"]"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "catalogs": {
        "sah-technical-catalog": {
            "_version": "1.1",
            "identification": {
                "id": "sah-technical-catalog",
                "namespace": "sah-tech-catalog",
                "title": "{{TECH_CATALOGS}}",
                "description": "",
                "entityType": "catalog",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties"
            },
            "payload": {
                "appDescriptors": [{
                    "id":"sah-grp-manage"
                }, {
                    "id":"sah-msg-manage"               
                }, {
                    "id":"sah-ops-activities"               
                }, {
                    "id":"sah-quick-loader"             
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "roles": {
        "Everyone": {
            "_version": "1.0",
            "identification": {
                "id": "Everyone",
                "title": "Everyone",
                "entityType": "role"
            },
            "payload": {
                "catalogs": [
                    "sah-technical-catalog"
                ],
                "groups": [{
                    "id": "user-applications"
                },
                {
                "id": "configuration-applications"
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "applications": {
        "sah-grp-manage":{
            "sap.app": {
                "_version": "1.5.0",
                "id": "sah-grp-manage",
                "type": "application",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "title": "{{appTitle}}",
                "description": "{{appDescription}}",
                "tags": {
                    "keywords": []
                },
                "crossNavigation": {
                    "inbounds": {
                        "groupManage": {
                            "semanticObject": "group",
                            "action": "manage",
                            "deviceTypes": {
                                "desktop": true,
                                "tablet": true,
                                "phone": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outbounds": {

                    }
                }
            },
            "sap.platform.hcp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "uri": "/manageGroup",
                "appName": ""
            },
            "sap.flp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "type": "UI5",
                "config": {
                    "skipVariantResolving": ""
                }
            },
            "sap.ui": {
                "_version": "1.3.0",
                "technology": "UI5",
                "deviceTypes": {
                    "desktop": true,
                    "tablet": true,
                    "phone": true
                }
            },
            "sap.ui5": {
                "componentName": "com.sap.groups",
                "_version": "1.1.0"
            },
            "sap.platform.cf": {
                "oAuthScopes": ["$XSAPPNAME.DISPLAY_GROUPS"]
            }
        },
        "sah-msg-manage":{
            "sap.app": {
                "_version": "1.5.0",
                "id": "sah-msg-manage",
                "type": "application",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "title": "{{MSG_BUILDER}}",
                "description": "{{MSG_BLD_DESC}}",
                "tags": {
                    "keywords": []
                },
                "crossNavigation": {
                    "inbounds": {
                        "groupManage": {
                            "semanticObject": "message",
                            "action": "manage",
                            "deviceTypes": {
                                "desktop": true,
                                "tablet": true,
                                "phone": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outbounds": {

                    }
                }
            },
            "sap.platform.hcp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "uri": "/manageMessage",
                "appName": ""
            },
            "sap.flp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "type": "UI5",
                "config": {
                    "skipVariantResolving": ""
                }
            },
            "sap.ui": {
                "_version": "1.3.0",
                "technology": "UI5",
                "deviceTypes": {
                    "desktop": true,
                    "tablet": true,
                    "phone": true
                }
            },
            "sap.ui5": {
                "componentName": "com.sap.messageList",
                "_version": "1.1.0"
            },
            "sap.platform.cf": {
                "oAuthScopes": ["$XSAPPNAME.MANAGE_MESSAGES"]
            }
        },
        "sah-grp-edit":{
            "sap.app": {
                "_version": "1.5.0",
                "id": "sah-grp-edit",
                "type": "application",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "title": "{{appTitle}}",
                "description": "{{appDescription}}",
                "tags": {
                    "keywords": []
                },
                "crossNavigation": {
                    "inbounds": {
                        "groupEdit": {
                            "semanticObject": "group",
                            "action": "edit",
                            "deviceTypes": {
                                "desktop": true,
                                "tablet": true,
                                "phone": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outbounds": {

                    }
                }
            },
            "sap.platform.hcp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "uri": "/editGroup",
                "appName": ""
            },
            "sap.flp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "type": "UI5",
                "config": {
                    "skipVariantResolving": ""
                }
            },
            "sap.ui": {
                "_version": "1.3.0",
                "technology": "UI5",
                "deviceTypes": {
                    "desktop": true,
                    "tablet": true,
                    "phone": true
                }
            },
            "sap.ui5": {
                "componentName": "ALPAPP",
                "_version": "1.1.0"
            },
            "sap.platform.cf": {
                "oAuthScopes": ["$XSAPPNAME.DISPLAY_GROUPS"]
            }
        },
        "sah-msg-create":{
            "sap.app": {
                "_version": "1.5.0",
                "id": "sah-msg-create",
                "type": "application",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "title": "{{MSG_CREATE}}",
                "description": "{{MSG_CREATE_DESC}}",
                "tags": {
                    "keywords": []
                },
                "crossNavigation": {
                    "inbounds": {
                        "groupEdit": {
                            "semanticObject": "message",
                            "action": "create",
                            "deviceTypes": {
                                "desktop": true,
                                "tablet": true,
                                "phone": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outbounds": {

                    }
                }
            },
            "sap.platform.hcp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "uri": "/createMessage",
                "appName": ""
            },
            "sap.flp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "type": "UI5",
                "config": {
                    "skipVariantResolving": ""
                }
            },
            "sap.ui": {
                "_version": "1.3.0",
                "technology": "UI5",
                "deviceTypes": {
                    "desktop": true,
                    "tablet": true,
                    "phone": true
                }
            },
            "sap.ui5": {
                "componentName": "com.sap.messageBuilder",
                "_version": "1.1.0"
            },
            "sap.platform.cf": {
                "oAuthScopes": ["$XSAPPNAME.MANAGE_MESSAGES"]
            }
        },
        "sah-ops-activities":{
            "sap.app": {
                "_version": "1.5.0",
                "id": "sah-ops-activities",
                "type": "application",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "title": "{{CONFIG_TITILE}}",
                "description": "{{appDescription}}",
                "tags": {
                    "keywords": []
                },
                "crossNavigation": {
                    "inbounds": {
                        "groupManage": {
                            "semanticObject": "activities",
                            "action": "operation",
                            "deviceTypes": {
                                "desktop": true,
                                "tablet": true,
                                "phone": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outbounds": {

                    }
                }
            },
            "sap.platform.hcp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "uri": "/operationalActivities",
                "appName": ""
            },
            "sap.flp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "type": "UI5",
                "config": {
                    "skipVariantResolving": ""
                }
            },
            "sap.ui": {
                "_version": "1.3.0",
                "technology": "UI5",
                "deviceTypes": {
                    "desktop": true,
                    "tablet": true,
                    "phone": true
                }
            },
            "sap.ui5": {
                "componentName": "com.sap.operational_activities",
                "_version": "1.1.0"
            },
            "sap.platform.cf": {
                "oAuthScopes": ["$XSAPPNAME.OPERATIONS"]
            }
        },
        "sah-quick-loader":{
            "sap.app": {
                "_version": "1.5.0",
                "id": "sah-quick-loader",
                "type": "application",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "title": "{{LOADER_TITILE}}",
                "description": "{{appDescription}}",
                "tags": {
                    "keywords": []
                },
                "crossNavigation": {
                    "inbounds": {
                        "groupManage": {
                            "semanticObject": "activities",
                            "action": "quickLoader",
                            "deviceTypes": {
                                "desktop": true,
                                "tablet": true,
                                "phone": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outbounds": {

                    }
                }
            },
            "sap.platform.hcp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "uri": "/quickLoader",
                "appName": ""
            },
            "sap.flp": {
                "_version": "1.1.0",
                "type": "UI5",
                "config": {
                    "skipVariantResolving": ""
                }
            },
            "sap.ui": {
                "_version": "1.3.0",
                "technology": "UI5",
                "deviceTypes": {
                    "desktop": true,
                    "tablet": true,
                    "phone": true
                }
            },
            "sap.ui5": {
                "componentName": "com.sap.quickloader",
                "_version": "1.1.0"
            },
            "sap.platform.cf": {
                "oAuthScopes": ["$XSAPPNAME.OPERATIONS"]
            }
        }
    },
    "groups": {
        "user-applications": {
            "identification": {
                "id": "user-applications",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "namespace": "user.applications",
                "title": "{{LAUNCHPAD_TITLE}}"
            },
            "payload": {
                "tiles": [{
                    "id": "sah-grp-manage",
                    "title": "{{GRP_MANAGEMENT}}",
                    "description": "{{SAH_APP}}",
                    "icon": "sap-icon://family-care",                   
                    "target": {
                        "semanticObject": "group",
                        "action": "manage",
                        "parameters": []
                    }
                },{
                    "id": "sah-msg-manage",
                    "title": "{{MSG_BUILDER}}",
                    "description": "{{MSG_BLD_DESC}}",
                    "icon": "sap-icon://email",                 
                    "target": {
                        "semanticObject": "message",
                        "action": "manage",
                        "parameters": []
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "configuration-applications": {
            "identification": {
                "id": "configuration-applications",
                "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
                "title": "{{CONFIGURATIONS_TITLE}}"
            },
            "payload": {
                "tiles": [{
                    "id": "sah-ops-activities",
                    "title": "{{OPERATIONS}}",
                    "description": "{{SAH_APP}}",
                    "icon": "sap-icon://action-settings",                   
                    "target": {
                        "semanticObject": "activities",
                        "action": "operation",
                        "parameters": []
                    }
                },{
                    "id": "sah-quick-loader",
                    "title": "{{quickLoader}}",
                    "description": "{{SAH_APP}}",
                    "icon": "sap-icon://upload",                    
                    "target": {
                        "semanticObject": "activities",
                        "action": "quickLoader",
                        "parameters": []
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "siteThemes": {
        "sap_hcb": {
            "description": "SAP High Contrast Black",
            "name": "sap_hcb",
            "path": "sap_hcb"
        },
        "sap_belize_plus": {
            "description": "SAP Belize Plus",
            "name": "sap_belize_plus",
            "path": "sap_belize_plus"
        },
        "sap_belize": {
            "description": "SAP Belize",
            "name": "sap_belize",
            "path": "sap_belize"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the tiles in the launchpad manager ?

Is this on prem or on the cloud ?

This blog covers MTA sorry, missed that part of your question:- https://blogs.sap.com/2018/10/29/develop-your-first-sap-fiori-launchpad-site-with-portal-service-on-sap-cloud-platform-multi-cloud-chapter-2/

This blog shows you how to set it up for on prem with some great easy to follow screen shots https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/19/sap-fiori-ui5-app-configuration-in-sap-fiori-launchpad/

ANd here Meredith takes you through deployment from the cloud https://developers.sap.com/uk/tutorials/teched-2017-fiori-deploy.html